# How to check if user is authenticated in AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs, auth0

I am using Auth0 in my AngularJS 1.x.x app.

The way I have the app set up is by using `div ng-if="isAuthenticated"` to display (and hide) `div`'s in my templates.  However, I want to be able to prevent API calls in my controllers if the user is not authenticated.  What is the correct syntax to block those calls?

I think I'm looking for something like:

```
if (isAuthenticated) {
      ServerRequest.getAllPatients({
      }).then(function(resp){
        $scope.myTestData = resp
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });
  } else { alert("you are not logged in") }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the exact requirements but in general you would have an Angular service that keeps track if the user is authenticated or not and the you inject this service wherever you need to apply conditional logic based of the authentication status.

Another possibility would be to completely reject the navigation to certain routes if those routes require an authenticated user and there isn't one. You could check this article for some guidance ([Deal with users authentication in an AngularJS web app](https://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app/)).